# PHP uploads and checking

Tags: php, javascript

**Edited:**

Sorry for the inconvenience, when i look back the codes, it does not actually upload the files, it's only capture the file's info and store in the database, which later cannot be download by user coz there not exist such file anywhere... my questions is, how can i integrate this codes with `move_uploaded_file()` function?

---

I want to update/insert file by using upload box to the database but before that it will check for the file type thats only pdf can be upload. Somthing wrong with the codes and i dont know what..Please help

here are part of my updates codes:

```
$id=$rs['id']; 
$qry = "SELECT a.faillampiran FROM {$CFG->prefix}ptk_lampiran a, {$CFG->prefix}ptk b WHERE a.ptkid=$id and b.id=$id";

$sql = get_records_sql($qry);
if($_POST['check']){     
    $ext = pathinfo($faillampiran,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);      
    $err = "Upload Only PDF File. ";    
    if ($ext =='pdf'){          
        $qry="UPDATE {$CFG->prefix}ptk_lampiran SET 
        faillampiran='".$faillampiran."'                
        WHERE ptkid='".$_GET['id']."'";
        $sql=mysql_query($qry);     
        $qry = "SELECT a.faillampiran FROM {$CFG->prefix}ptk_lampiran a, {$CFG->prefix}ptk b
            WHERE b.id = '".$rs[id]."' AND a.ptkid = '".$rs[id]."' ";
        $sql = get_records_sql($qry);
        foreach($sql as $rs){ ?>              
            <?=basename($rs->faillampiran); ?><br>
        <? } 
        ?>              
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td>
        <input type="file" size="50" name="faillampiran" alt="faillampiran" value= "<?=$faillampiran;?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="edit" value="Muat naik fail ini" /><br />
        </td></tr>  
    }       
    else {
        echo "<script>alert('$err')</script>";
    }

} else { 

foreach($sql as $rs){ ?>              
    <?=basename($rs->faillampiran); ?><br>
<? } 

?>
<input type="file" size="50" name="faillampiran" alt="faillampiran" value= "<?=$faillampiran;?>" />
<input type="submit" name="edit" value="Muat naik fail ini" /><br />
<?}
```

Sori bout the messiness of the codes, im still a beginner in this languages.

thx

Comment: what happens? what doesn't work?

Comment: Please add more information. What happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: what is "something wrong" in this case? do you get error messages - and if yes, could you please post this? are other files uploadable? please provide a little more info...

Comment: your coding is correct, tell me about your problem

Answer (score 0):

You've provided no details of why you think it fails.

However using my crystal ball, I see that you are checking if the file extension is '.pdf'. I guess you're looking at `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` or `$_FILES['userfile']['name']`. The latter will only match if the extension was in lower case on the client. The former won't ever match.

> it will check for the file type thats only pdf

That's not what your code does at all. A file extension only matches the contents *by convention* and *only on some architectures*

C.

Comment: what is the different between $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] or $_FILES['userfile']['name']. and pathinfo($faillampiran,PATHINFO_BASENAME); which i used in the codes?

Comment: 1) the name of the file allocated by PHP for temporary storage after an upload - which will not have mime related ext, 2) the name of the file on the client system before it was uploaded - where the ext is whatever the user chose, 3) I have no idea - it's something generated by your code / data